# HDD refuses to live right after Ubuntu's been installed on machine

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive

So, i had this ancient desktop machine (i think it shipped with Windows Vista if not XP), some AMD-based chipset and i decided to put an Ubuntu server on it. I made a bootable USB thingie with server 20.04.1, booted up, installation ploughed through the old windows partition, all was great, updates downloaded, flowers blossomed, women liked me - reboot! And from here on it all got only weirder and weirder. Whenever the HDD (SATA) which we just installed onto is hooked up to the machine, it hangs dead right after the mobo goes through hard drive detection. Like, i cannot even go into BIOS because apparently it only reads keyboard after HDDs said "hi". I think it's actually several steps before it would even start booting. If i unplug the hard drive, the machine would boot normally from either usb or optical.
This was my first brush with Ubuntu, like, at all, so i have to ask: is there a chance the installer could have done something so evil that the drive went gaga on such level? Or am i just that lucky and it died of natural causes exactly now? (it is a possibility, it's really old, haven't been used in a while and lived a generally difficult life in a cold shed and now suddenly worked pretty hard installing all this fancy software).

Comment: I can't see how an OS installation makes any difference (it's just data codes stored on the disk, with no special powers) so I'd be suspicious of hardware as described. As PSUs age, they provide less power, and it maybe the power required to spin the drive is causing strain causing lock-up (components can misbehave when insufficient power is provided..) I would check the health of the drive in another box using it's S.M.A.R.T. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: I mean, in theory the installer could try to be smart about CMOS settings, AFAIK, but that's probably not the case anyway, since everything about the hdd was and still is on autodetect... Right, will try with the next victim...